# Problem on subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Q.** Prove that if $W$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ and $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ are in $W$, then $a_1w_1+a_2w_2+\ldots+a_nw_n\in W$ for any scalars $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$.

**Attempt at solution:**

Let us denote by $F$ the field over which the vector space $V$ is taken. Then, since $W$ is a subspace of $V(F)$, it should itself be a vector space over $F$ and must satisfy the following two preliminary definitions :

$$x,y\in W\implies x+y\in W\tag1$$

$$x\in W\implies \alpha x\in W~\forall ~\alpha\in F\tag2$$

We're given that $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n\in W$ and $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in F$ since they are scalars.

By $(2)$, we have that, $a_iw_i\in W~\forall~i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\tag3$

By $(3)$ and $(1)$, we have,

$$\sum_{i=1}^na_iw_i=a_1w_1+a_2w_2+\ldots+a_nw_n\in W$$

And we 're done. $_\square$

---

Is the solution good, i.e., can I write this in a test? Also, I'd like fellow MSE users to point out any mistakes, if any and also suggest improvements maybe. Thanks!

Comment: It is correct! 
Since you ask: if you want you can point out that $\sum_1^n a_i w_i$ is in $W$ because this is a sum over a finite number of elements. Alternatively you can be pedant explaining that you take $z_1=a_1w_1$, $z_2=z_1+a_2w_2$ and going on until you get $z_n=z_{n-1}+a_nw_n$, in this way you clarify that what you are doing is applying (1) iteratively, and not doing a sum "all-in-one".